# Tableau Graph - Histogram

Tags: graph, histogram, tableau-api

can you please help me find resources to create a very specific type of graph on Tableau? I think it is a histogram graph but messing around with the graph I can't get it to look exactly like the one in the image. I need to create the exact same graph.

The Dimensions are: Category, Brand, Data

The Measures are: Points

[Points by Date Range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEU9b.jpg)

[image]

Comment: can you attach workbook?

Comment: Hi Siva, yes please find the workbook here: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=136n3Q28Hfi-rIkG-rEz1Q575x4xTPnQ0)

Comment: what is it on X-axis 1-10

Comment: Hi Vishal, it is time. So in this case it is week number and you can filter to month number as well.

Comment: It would have better if you have attached the tableau workbook... if you can attach tableau workbook then attach as a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this workbook](https://public.tableau.com/views/ParameterizedDateView/Dashboard?:embed=y&:display_count=yes&:toolbar=no) published to Tableau Public. It is quite close to the reference image posted on the question, including the combo boxes. You can download the workbook from webpage.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect

Comment: The filters are great as well, I got quite far with these but didn't get the Group by working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

If yes, I can share tableau workbook, If not let me know what is missing?

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that looks perfect! Please send the file

Comment: Do you have any shared location? if yes provide link will upload the tableau workbook

Comment: Sorry, for the late feedback. I don't have a shared location, is there any way you could upload to google drive and share with me from there?